# How to Access MdiParent Controls From Child Form C++ .NET

Tags: c++, .net, forms, parent-child, mdiparent

I need to put a `ToolStripMenuItem` on `Enabled` from a `Child` Form in `C++ .NET`. I try to search this on internet, but nothing for C++, all the answers ware for C#.

I try this but don't work (`menu_open` is the `ToolStripMenuItem` ):

```
this->MdiParent->Controls["menu_open"]->Enabled=true;
```

I try:

```
(Form1)this->MdiParent->Controls["menu_open"]->Enabled=true;
```

and

```
((Form1)this->MdiParent)->Controls["menu_open"]->Enabled=true;
```

but don't find the `Form1` that is the parent. Please help.

I try this: add the line

```
ref class Form1;
```

inside the namespace of the child form and the line

```
 Form1^ parent;
```

inside of the `public ref class Child` .. . Now I have an object of parent form and I try:

```
parent->Controls["menu_open"]->Enabled = true;
```

But I have this errors:

```
   use of undefined type 'DataLogger::Form1'
   left of '->Controls' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
   left of '->Enabled' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
   use of undefined type 'DataLogger::Form1'       
   left of '->Controls' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
   left of '->Enabled' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If enyone will have the same problem, I found the answer. You will need to use the `MdiChildActivate` event of the parent form. This event will appear when the child is created and when the cild is closed, to resolve this probleme, use this code:

Create a private varible outside the function set on 0:

```
private: static int closeChild = 0;
```

In `private: System::Void Form1_MdiChildActivate(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)` use this code:

```
closeChild++;
String ^ childName = this->MdiChildren[0]->Text;

if(closeChild == 2)
   menu_open->Enabled=true;
```

`closeChild` will be 2 on closing. **And don't forget to reset `closeChild` to 0 when a new child is created becouse `closeChild` will increment to 3, etc..**

Good luck !